# How to evaluate expressions inside mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to evaluate expressions inside a `mutate()` command and I'm getting errors. Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
depvar <- "foo"
transformedvars[1] <- "mean(bar)"

dataset %>% mutate(paste0("t", depvar) = transformedvars[1])
```

I want to use `mutate()` to create a column called `tfoo` and have it take as values the result of calling up `mean(bar)`, where `bar` is another column in my data.

The error I am getting is:

> Error: unexpected '=' in: "dataset %>% mutate(paste0("t", depvar) ="

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This requires `rlang`. First, I create a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(bar = runif(10))

#            bar
# 1  0.549319057
# 2  0.351898657
# 3  0.326850457
# 4  0.951580599
# 5  0.712514111
# 6  0.425802253
# 7  0.240621368
# 8  0.002803366
# 9  0.471586186
# 10 0.387040517
```

Next, I state my variable name and transformation:

```
dep_var <- "foo"
tran_var <- "mean(bar)"
```

Finally, I use `!!` to unquote the string I create with `paste` and the parsed string from `parse_quosure`.

```
df %>% mutate(!!paste("t", dep_var, sep = "") := !!parse_quosure(tran_var))

#            bar      tfoo
# 1  0.549319057 0.4420017
# 2  0.351898657 0.4420017
# 3  0.326850457 0.4420017
# 4  0.951580599 0.4420017
# 5  0.712514111 0.4420017
# 6  0.425802253 0.4420017
# 7  0.240621368 0.4420017
# 8  0.002803366 0.4420017
# 9  0.471586186 0.4420017
# 10 0.387040517 0.4420017
```

---

### Edit

Checking the documentation, it looks like `parse_quosure` was 'soft-deprecated' and so the following may be more up-to-date:

```
df %>% mutate(!!paste("t", dep_var, sep = "") := !!parse_quo(tran_var, env = caller_env()))
```

Comment: I brought in rlang, reran the code, and it worked!!! Thanks! I'll add rlang to my reading list.

Comment: Shouldn't that quosure be created with the correct environment, rather than `.GlobalEnv`?  This just seems unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @user2554330 I've updated the edit. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Looks better.  Using "env = df" worked for me, and seemed to make sense:  but see my non-tidyverse answer for what I think is a simpler solution to this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use Tidyverse code here at all, when base R code is much clearer:

```
newname <- paste0("t", depvar)
df[, newname] <- with(df, eval(parse(text = transformedvars[1])))
```

It could all be done in one line as

```
df[, paste0("t", depvar)] <- with(df, eval(parse(text = transformedvars[1])))
```

but I think the two line version is easier to read.

Comment: tidyverse version looks pretty clear to me, and it works well in a pipeline.

Comment: The original version in the question looks clear, but doesn't work.  The one that works (in Lyngbakr's answer) isn't clear at all, at least to me.  Based on the comment from the OP ("it worked!!!"), maybe not so clear to him, either.

Comment: Well, for someone who is not familiar with `rlang` or the `tidyverse` ecosystem, it might not be clear, but I would argue that even in that case, `eval` + `parse` is not any easier to understand. If you meant that his "explanation" is not clear enough, that's fair, but I don't see much in your answer either.

Comment: No, I meant the code is hard to understand, not the answer.  The surprising use of `.GlobalEnv` in `parse_quo` (when you really want the expression evaluated in the dataframe environment, not the global environment) really needs thinking about.  But you are right about my version not fitting into a pipeline.

Comment: And in defense of `eval` and `parse`:  at least they are documented.  `parse_quo` doesn't even show up in the usage section of its help page.

Comment: `.GlobalEnv` is the environment of the quosure, not the environment in which it will be evaluated. `!!` evaluates the quosure immediately in the surrounding environment. `parse_quo` does show up in `?parse_quo` under "Life cycle" if you read carefully. Nonetheless, it all depends on what you're familiar with. It's not fair to say that some answer is less clear because you're less familiar with the package.

Comment: I think it's completely fair to say that code is clearer if it places less of a load on the reader.  To understand `parse_quo`, you need to understand what `parse` does; to understand the `!!` operator, you need to understand `eval`.  The reverse is not true.

Comment: With that logic, no one should use any packages at all since all of them are built on top of base R functions. The point of packages is to extend the functionality of Base R that may of may not be more convenient. Whether that new way of doing things is "clearer", on the other hand, is subjective and largely depends on your initial familiarity with the package. My point is that you shouldn't definitively say to stick to Base R because you find it easier to understand than a package you're not familiar with.

Comment: No, I'm saying that in *this* case the additions in those packages don't actually improve things, they make things harder to understand.  In other cases they do help.

Comment: Returning to this, I'll add some context. The question came from a larger project that I'm adding to, not writing from scratch, and there's more to this particular pipeline, so I was locked into the tidyverse. But thanks for the un-tidy version!

Answer (score 0):

using the variables defined above, one could also do:

```
set.seed(29)
df <- data.frame(bar = runif(10))

tran_var <- "2*bar+1"

df %>% mutate(tfoo = !!parse_expr(tran_var))
# or 
# df %>% mutate(tfoo = eval(parse_expr(tran_var)))

#          bar     tfoo
#1  0.09968104 1.199362
#2  0.24090211 1.481804
#3  0.10321380 1.206428
#4  0.32558388 1.651168
#5  0.58498881 2.169978
#6  0.09308678 1.186174
#7  0.82816760 2.656335
#8  0.86630509 2.732610
#9  0.11999244 1.239985
#10 0.23314674 1.466293
```